# REACT.js Error: " Cannot read property ' methods ' of null

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web3js

I'm following an online tutorial to learn how DAPP applications work and while my code matches the tutorial, I am receiving an error that they are not. I've been searching for several hours now and while I can find similar errors and that match mine, the solutions don't seem to work. I was hoping someone here might be able to take a look and see what could be causing the issue.

There are 2 buttons; one for deposit, and another for withdraw. For the onClick event of either, I am receiving this error in the console (I currently have the error piped to the console in a try/catch):

" Error, deposit:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'methods' of null "

Is there anyone who might be able to help me shed some light on this? I have already tried reaching out to the host of the tutorial and commenting in the comment section, but I have not had a reply.

Here is the App.js code:

```js
import { Tabs, Tab } from 'react-bootstrap'
import dBank from '../abis/dBank.json'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Token from '../abis/Token.json'
import dbank from '../dbank.png';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import './App.css';

//h0m3w0rk - add new tab to check accrued interest

class App extends Component {

  async componentWillMount() {
    await this.loadBlockchainData(this.props.dispatch)
  }

  async loadBlockchainData(dispatch) {
    //check if MetaMask exists, else push alert
    if(typeof window.ethereum!=='undefined') {

      await window.ethereum.enable()
      const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
      const netId = await web3.eth.net.getId()
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()

      if(typeof accounts[0] !=='undefined') {
        //check if account is detected, then load balance&setStates, else push alert
        const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0])
        this.setState({ account: accounts[0], balance: balance, web3: web3 })
        } else {
          //MetaMask not connected alert
          window.alert('MetaMask is detected, but not connected. Please accept the connection and login through MetaMask.')
          }

        //load contracts with try-catch error handling in case of error loading contracts
      try{
        //load Token contract
        const token = new web3.eth.Contract(Token.abi, Token.networks[netId].address)
        //load Bank contract and save address to variable
        const dbank = new web3.eth.Contract(dBank.abi, dBank.networks[netId].address)
        const dBankAddress = dBank.networks[netId].address
        //saved to state
        this.setState({token: token, dBank: dBank, dBankAddress: dBankAddress})
        } catch (e) {
          //contracts not loaded error
          console.log('Error', e)
          window.alert('Contracts are not deployed to the current network.')
          }
  
    } else {
      //MetaMask not detected alert
      window.alert('MetaMask is required to use this service. Please install MetaMask.')
      }

  }

  async deposit(amount) {

    //check if this.state.dbank is ok
    if(this.state.dbank!=='undefined'){
      try{
        await this.state.dbank.methods.deposit().send({value: amount.toString(), from: this.state.account})
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error, deposit: ', e)
      }
    }
  }

  async withdraw(e) {
    //prevent button from default click
    e.preventDefault()
    //check if this.state.dbank is ok
    if(this.state.dbank!=='undefined'){
      try{
        await this.state.dbank.methods.withdraw().send({from: this.state.account})
      } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error, withdraw: ', e)
      }
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      web3: 'undefined',
      account: '',
      token: null,
      dbank: null,
      balance: 0,
      dBankAddress: null
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='text-monospace'>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
          <a
            className="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0"
            href="www.pantheon.finance"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
        <img src={dbank} className="App-logo" alt="logo" height="65"/>
          <b> Pantheon Decentralized Investments</b>
        </a>
        </nav>
        <div className="container-fluid mt-5 text-center">
        <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <h1>Welcome to Pantheon Decentralized Investments</h1>
          <h2>Your connected address is:</h2>
          <h2>{this.state.account}</h2>
          <br></br>
          <div className="row">
            <main role="main" className="col-lg-12 d-flex text-center">
              <div className="content mr-auto ml-auto">
              <Tabs defaultActiveKey="profile" id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
                <Tab eventKey="deposit" title="Deposit">
                  <div>
                    <br></br>
                    How much would you like to deposit?
                    <br></br>
                    (Only one deposit of a min. 0.01 ETH allowable at a time)
                    <br></br>
                    <form onSubmit={(e) => {
                      e.preventDefault()
                      let amount = this.depositAmount.value
                      amount = Web3.utils.toWei(amount.toString(), 'ether') //converts amount to wei
                      this.deposit(amount)
                    }}>
                      <div className='form-group mr-sm-2'>
                      <br></br>
                        <input
                          id='depositAmount'
                          step="0.01"
                          type='number'
                          className="form-control form-control-md"
                          placeholder='amount...'
                          required
                          ref={(input) => { this.depositAmount = input }}
                        />
                      </div>
                      <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>DEPOSIT</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </Tab>
                <Tab eventKey="withdraw" title="Withdraw">
                  <br></br>
                    Would you like to withdraw your investment + interest earned?
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>                  
                  <div>
                    <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary' onClick={(e) => this.withdraw(e)}>WITHDRAW</button>
                  </div>
                </Tab>
              </Tabs>
              </div>
            </main>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `this.state.dbank` is null, but the code only guards against `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check the null or undefined value, replace the code as below

```
if(this.state.dbank){
  //....your code
}
```

in your code you check only for "undefined" value while `this.state.dbank` initialized as null after calling `this.loadBlockchainData()` method, it's not going inside if block `if(typeof accounts[0] !=='undefined') {}` and still it's into initial null state

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new so I may not understand you, but I will try. So you are saying that the issue is because I have checked for ' undefined ' when I should be checking for null? In that case, I should change the IF statement on line 60 from:

if(this.state.dbank!=='undefined'){

}

to this instead?

if(this.state.dbank){
    
}

Comment: you should be checking for both null and undefined, I've provided you above example for the same

Comment: Yes @MichaelMorris once you replace with  if(this.state.dbank) condition, you will not get above error.

Comment: Thank you. I will study more about this is try to better understand it, thank you again for your help. 

I think that stopped the error. But I may have found another issue. For some reason, I am not getting the approval prompt in metamask. I previously had some issues connecting metamask to my ganache and through web3, so I think I need to go back through all those steps again. This might be an ambitious project for a beginner like myself.  :-)

Comment: welcome.. keep learning..  All the best.
Please upvote the answer

Comment: I tried to upvote, but it said I need 15 reputation before I can make upvotes...? But I won't forget you, I'll come back and upvote when I'm allowed to make upvotes on my account. 

By the way, I think I figured out what you meant by checking for both null AND undefined. I wrapped the original statement inside the IF statement you recommended making it a nested IF and it seems to be working. :-)